# default fixed port collision for 22 = 2222. now on port 2200 on vagrant hang-up

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, virtual-machine, 64-bit, vagrant

I'm using virtual box 5.0 and vagrant 1.8 on windows 7 64bit and one of the debian base 32bit box running on machine.

Now I've installing another debian 64bit bit on vagrant and but showing below error and stuck:

```
==> default: fixed port collision for 22 = 2222. now on port 2200

*** hang-up ***
```

Following step/note done :

- Reinstall virtual box and used 4.3.x and 5.0.x and also used vagrant 1.6 and 1.8.x.
- This vagrant file work in another windows 7 64bit machine.
- VT feature enable in BIOS
- also try to add `config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 22, host: 2210, id: "ssh", auto_correct: true` and `config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 22 host: 2210`

I've do the googling but not get solution, Any one have idea about this ?

Comment: That error is really just information, saying that it is switching the default port.  It probably isn't related to your problem.  But you are saying that it hangs at this point?

Comment: @paul yes it's hangup after this, why?

Comment: Revert to the default configuration and run with `--debug`. Update the question.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this. I am also having the same problem. Could not find any solution.

Comment: @AnkurBhatia Yes, I was an issue of powershell version, After the upgrade powershell 2 to 3, resolved issue

Comment: @ServerNinja Thanks for the reply. I am actually facing this on Fedora 24.

Comment: @AnkurBhatia you just execute "vagrant up --debug" and let me know error

Comment: @ServerNinja Thanks for the reply. I ran it with debug mode. It gets stuck at the following:
DEBUG subprocess: Waiting for process to exit. Remaining to timeout: 32000
DEBUG subprocess: Exit status: 0
 INFO warden: Calling IN action: #<Vagrant::Action::Builtin::SyncedFolders:0x00000004014970>
 INFO synced_folders: SyncedFolders loading from cache: false
 INFO synced_folders: Synced Folder Implementation: rsync

Comment: INFO synced_folders:   - /home/vagrant/sync: . => /home/vagrant/sync
 INFO synced_folders: Synced Folder Implementation: virtualbox
 INFO synced_folders:   - /vagrant: . => /vagrant
 INFO synced_folders: Invoking synced folder prepare for: rsync
 INFO synced_folders: Invoking synced folder prepare for: virtualbox
 INFO subprocess: Starting process: ["/usr/bin/VBoxManage", "setextradata", "d0107ce4-bf97-4483-b850-4d7f56e1cca3", "VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/vagrant", "1"]
 INFO subprocess: Command not in installer, restoring original environment...

Comment: DEBUG subprocess: Selecting on IO